# How to deal with $P(X_2=1, X_1\in\{0,2\}, X_0=1)? $

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

For a Markov chain with state-space, $\{0,1,2\}$, how to deal with
$$
P(X_2=1, X_1\in\{0,2\}, X_0=1)?
$$
Is this one equal to
$$
P(X_2=1, X_1=0, X_0=1)+ P(X_2=1, X_1=2, X_0=1)?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok to me. To justify it, let $$A=\{X_0=1\},B=\{X_1=0\},C=\{X_1=2\},D=\{X_2=1\}.$$ Then since $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive,

$$P(A\cap D\cap (B\cup C))=P((A\cap D\cap B)\cup (A\cap D\cap C))=P(A\cap D\cap B)+P(A\cap D\cap C).$$

---

Note $A=\{X_0=1\}$ is shorthand for $A=\{X_0,X_1,X_2:X_0=1\}$ etc.